# Why is log4j logging redirected to stderr in a webapp deployed on Weblogic?

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic, slf4j

An webapp deployed in Weblogic is using SLF4J with Log4j for logging, but all the logging ends up in the STDERR, without any possible reason.

1. Checked the start-up parameter on the Weblogic server: -Dweblogic.Stderr=/opt/logs/exp.err
2. Checked if the "Redirect stderr logging enabled" is not true and the other logging settings in the Weblogic console, is not true
3. Checked and removed all the forgotten log4j.properties in the source code.
4. Searched for System.setErr() in the code, which could redirect the Log4J output to STDERR, not found anything
5. Adapted the versions of Log4J (1.2.13 and 1.2.16) and SLF4J (1.6.4 and 1.7.7) without any change
6. Added jcl-over-slf4j and jul-to-slf4j to Maven dependencies
7. Set Log4J and SLF4J as "provided", since these are a part of the general server libs to avoid conflicts
8. Complete refactoring to SLF4J - removed all occurrences of Log4j (Logger class) from the includes in all Java classes

This is the log4j configuration:

```
log4j.rootCategory                                      = WARN,fileA

log4j.appender.fileA                                   = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileA.file                              = /opt/logs/exp_application_log4j.log
log4j.appender.fileA.layout                            = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileA.Threshold                         = WARN
log4j.appender.fileA.layout.ConversionPattern          = %t %d %-5p | (%c:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileA.MaxFileSize                       = 10MB
log4j.appender.fileA.MaxBackupIndex                    = 5


log4j.category.com.pams                             = WARN
log4j.category.de                                   = WARN
log4j.category.com                                  = WARN
log4j.category.com.gti.cache                        = WARN
log4j.category.com.cs.pu                              = ERROR
log4j.category.com.cs.common                        = FATAL
log4j.category.com.cs                               = WARN
log4j.category.com.ino.dp                           = WARN
log4j.category.org.apache.fop                       = ERROR
```

Comment: Can you pass on the log4j xml file ?

Comment: It's not an XML, but the old style property file, attached.